# Adding images to canvas object doesn't display properly

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to add an image to a canvas object, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to get it to display properly. It shows the canvas object (a circle), but not the image.

Here is my canvas HTML:

```
  <canvas id="leaf" width="60" height="60" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

Below is the relevant JS:

```
let canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('leaf');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

let imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function()
{
  context.save();
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(30, 30, 28, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.clip();
  context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
};

imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';

context.restore();
context.beginPath();
context.arc(30, 30, 28, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
context.strokeStyle = 'red';
context.stroke();

console.log(canvas.toDataURL());

return canvas.toDataURL();
```

But instead of showing the image within the circle, it just displays the circle, without the image...
[image: red circle from canvas]

Comment: I got the image to display, unclipped, at the wrong aspect ratio, by removing `<HTMLCanvasElement>` and both lines with `canvas.toDataURL()`. Hope that helps.

Comment: By removing <HTMLCanvasElement>, I get the error that 'getContext' does not exist on HTMLElement. I also need the canvas.toDataURL() to export the canvas to be used on a google map.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that this was due to the `return canvas.toDataURL();` being called preemptively, so I moved it into the image.load() function, and now it displays properly!